# How to mount JBOD array HDs from NAS to recover data?

Tags: mount, data-recovery, fstab

I have four HDs from a crappy, dead NAS with data I'd like to retrieve.  I'm new to Linux, and Ubuntu, but have determined that the partition that has the data is `/dev/md125`.  However, I cannot mount this partition as it has an LVM2 PV filesystem, and is not found in `/etc/fstab`.

I'll read/research more, but maybe somebody knows something helpful (I hope).

More data, as per Terrance's suggestion:

`sudo apt install lvm2` results in:
`lvm2 is already the newest version (2.03.11-2-1ubuntu4).`

Output of lvscan:

```
user@PC:~$ sudo lvscan  
[sudo] password for user:   
  ACTIVE            '/dev/vg0/lv0' [17.26 TiB] inherit  
user@PC:~$
```

Comment: You will probably need to install `lvm2` so that you can read the LVM2 PV.  `sudo apt install lvm2`  Then you can run `lvscan` and add the output to your question.